# Corrupt an image with noise given the noise's distribution?

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I am developing a test bed in OpenCV and I would like to know how can I create a corrupted image given the image and a specific Probability Density Function of the required noise? In Digital Image Processing by Gonzalez and Woods [Chapter 5 of this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201508036) they give the PDF but I really can't seem to figure out how to calculate generate the noise in an image given the PDF. If someone can point me in the correct direction as to how I might start with the implementation I would be grateful. Even if the information is not in C\C++ I would appreciate any help thanks.

Comment: What PDF do you want to generate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach here is to try to simulate a histogram matching from uniform noise to the desired PDF.

1.) Calculate the CDF of the desired noise from your PDF.
2.) Generate a uniform random number 0-1.
3.) Find the value in the CDF that is closest to the random number.
4.) The index of the closest value in the CDF is the digital count in the noise image.

After doing this for each pixel, you should have a noise image with the desired PDF.